# How to get data (select's lines) from web service to xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to get all the results of a sql table's call (select *) in php, to send them to the iphone's app and use them there.

What steps would you recommend me?

I am a complete noob in xcode and php. I have some tests like this one:

```
   NSString *miURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hello.com/test.php];

   NSString *myRawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:miURL]];


   SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

   NSArray *list = [NSArray alloc];
   lista = [[parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:nil] copy];
```

And in the .php:

```
    <?php
        $conectID = mssql_connect("SERVIDOR\SQLEXPRESS","**","**");
        mssql_select_db("Animals");

        $result=mssql_query("select * from dbo.animals where name='jack'");
        $row=mssql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row){
            $myArray = array($row["name"], $row["type"], $row["colour"], $row["age"], $row["address"]);
            echo json_encode($myArray);
```

}

All of this is good and quick for a simple line.. but for a lot of lines from a sql's select would be very inefficient, doesn't it? 
Because I would like to execute for example: "select * from dbo.animals" and save each field of the table in its counterpart xcode's object's field. In xcode I would have a list of this:

```
    @interface DataPerfil : NSObject {    
       NSString *name;
       NSString *type;
       NSString *colour;
       NSInteger *age;           
       NSString *address;    
    }
    ....
```

I hope I have explained it well..

Sorry my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking real web service as in soap here is a tutorial I used :
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/0/page/1

It's more complex than your example but the web service layer adds security and hides the access to data.